# How can I remove informative text in Vs Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

[image]

I'm writing code in python and the text that appears in the picture is constantly appearing. How can I remove it?

Comment: try `Ctrl_Space`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `File >> Preferences >> Settings` and put

`"editor.hover.enabled": false` on the search box.

Disable it, then close and open Visual Code.

**Edit:** Thought we were talking about the one during hover, another you can try for when you are typing is:

```
"editor.parameterHints.enabled": false
```